# Image Corruption with Screenshots on Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, image-processing, whatsapp, screen-corruption

Whenever I try to upload an image that I saved with the Screenshot tool I get a corrupted looking image:

Example of corrupted image:

[image: Screenshot]

This seems to happen primarily when trying to upload/paste from clipboard when using a online messaging service (like whatsapp web).

Is there anyway to fix this ?

Comment: So the screenshot is not corrupt but becomes corrupt when you upload it? Describe specifically and stepwise what you do that causes the problem so that anyone can try tor reproduce that. Currently we do not have an idea how you upload, where you upload etc.